# Hyperbolic system with no zero eigenvalue

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, hyperbolic-pde

In the $n \times n$ hyperbolic system 
$$u_t + A(u)u_x = F(u)$$
what's the name of the assumption that $A$ has no zero eigenvalues?

Note that if the eigenvalues are all real and distinct the system is called strictly hyperbolic.

Comment: What's the significance of having no zero eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that a zero eigenvalue of $A(u)$ implies that the vector field $\partial_t$ is a *characteristic direction*. For instance, the equation $u_s + u_y = 0$ takes the form $u_t=0$ after switching to the coordinates $(t,x)=(s,y-s)$, where the spatial surfaces $t=$const and $s=$const are the same, while $\partial_t = \partial_s + \partial_y$. So perhaps you could say that when $A(u)$ has only real non-zero eigenvalues the system is "weakly hyperbolic with non-characteristic time".

Comment: Thanks. Could you just clarify what's the definition of a characteristic direction?

Comment: This doesn't agree with what I think of as a characteristic direction. What I think of as a noncharacteristic direction is one such that any initial data specified on a surface (here, a curve) transversal to the direction is well posed. Here, I believe $\partial_t$ is noncharacteristic in that sense. However, if the eigenvalue of $A$ is zero, then the initial value problem with initial data on the curve $x = 0$ is ill-posed. It is, however, well-posed, if $A$ is invertible, i.e., has no zero eigenvalues.

Comment: I more or less agree with Deane. The eigenvalues of $A$ are the characteristic velocities (wave speeds). I don't really see any significance of $A$ having no zero eigenvalues.

Comment: @DeaneYang I distinguish between characteristic _directions_ (elements of the characteristic cone in the tangent bundle, sometimes also called ray cone) and characteristic _surfaces_ (conormals are elements of the characteristic cone in the cotangent bundle). These two _distinct_ characteristic cones are duals of each other, of course. In my example, $t=0$ is a non-characteristic surface, but $\partial_t$ is a characteristic direction. On the other hand, $s-y=0$, which is the same as $x=0$, is a characteristic surface. Also notice that $\partial_t$ is tangent to $x=0$, as you would expect! :-)

Comment: @Zyl In your case, for fixed $u$, if $v$ is an eigenvalue of $A(u)$, then $\partial_t - v\partial_x$ is a characteristic direction or a ray vector. These vectors are the directions along which wave packets propagate in the geometric optics approximation. A characteristic (codimension-1) surface is any surface whose tangent plane contains at least one characteristic direction. These surfaces are wave fronts in the plane wave approximation.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine, yes, you're right. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Do you mean that if there is a zero eigenvalue there is a stationary wave solution?

Comment: @Zyl, why _stationary wave_? Perhaps you mean just _stationary_ (independent of $t$). Then the answer is Yes only in the very special case that your equation is linear, homogeneous with constant coefficients, because then the principal symbol determines the entire equation. More generally of course it is not true, and the answer is Yes only in some approximate sense (in as much as your equation can be approximated by one that is linear, homogeneous with constant coefficients, so only locally perhaps).